# without graphics changes can we flip image for right and left usage

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics

I had one image with left facing .

I want that image to face right direction.

Can we do it without any graphics changes.

by animation or other way?

I dont want to do it thru photoshop and increase my app size.

[image]

Comment: create a bitmap and rotate it?

Comment: @AndroSelva hay can't we do it thru xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29) to create a new bitmap with a matrix that can flip your original bitmap, for example this one:

```
| -1 0 0 |
|  0 1 0 |
|  0 0 1 |
```

And here is the code that does just that:

```
final Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setValues(new float[] { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1});
final Bitmap normalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.arrow);
final Bitmap flippedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(normalBitmap, 0, 0, normalBitmap.getWidth(), normalBitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this via CSS

```
img
{
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: hay for this I want an html page right. I am doing in android ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
      <translate
       android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="700" />
    </set>
```

set this xml coding to move from right to left for image view 
hope this will help you